# neo4j dotnet driver version 4.1.0 var records = await cursor.ToListAsync(); method does not complete

Tags: neo4j

I am having a problem with the Neo4j dotnet driver version 4.1.0. I am running the following query

```
MATCH (country:Country)
   CALL { WITH country OPTIONAL MATCH (person:Person)-[:TRAVELS_TO]->(country) RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT person.identifier) AS person_TRAVELS_TO_country }
   CALL { WITH country OPTIONAL MATCH (travelAgency:TravelAgency)-[:FLYING_TO]->(country) RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT travelAgency.identifier) AS travelAgency_FLYING_TO_country }
   RETURN country {.*
    , PERSON_TRAVELS_TO_COUNTRY: person_TRAVELS_TO_country
    , TRAVEL_AGENCY_FLYING_TO_COUNTRY: travelAgency_FLYING_TO_country 
  }
```

on the following graph:

[image: sample graph]

I am using the following code to query the database:

```
var cypher = "...";
var readTransaction = await session.BeginTransactionAsync();
var cursor = await readTransaction.RunAsync(cypher);
var records = await cursor.ToListAsync();
```

The last line in the above snippet never returns, it `hangs` there. I created a sample project on GitHub that demonstrates the problem https://github.com/samgerene/neo4j-net-driver-test

I also run the same cypher query on the HTTP API and that works just fine (if this issue cannot be resolved, i will use the HTTP API to get the data out)

Any help would be appreciated (I also reported this as an issue on the driver GitHub repository https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-dotnet-driver/issues/437)

Comment: Based on the feedback in the GitHub issue the short term solution is to downgrade to version 4.0.2 of the Neo4j.Driver.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a bug in the driver which has been fixed.